# PositionErrorはどこに定義さてるのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

#### 前提・実現したいこと

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`でエラーが発生すると`PositionError`が発生しますがPositionErrorがどこにも定義されておらず困っています。

`$q.defer( (resolve,reject) => navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(resolve,reject) )`の様なコードがあったとしてSPAでwatchしてる最中にページ移動した場合`reject`を呼びたいと思います。
rejectの定義は`function reject(error:PositionError)`としたいですよね？

そこでページ遷移のイベントをフックして`reject( new PositionError(3,'Timeout') )`(疑似コード)を発生させたいと思いますが`PositionError`の所在が分からないので困っています。

前述通り`error instanceOf PositionError`が通る形で解決策を探しております。

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Geolocation)のGeolocation関係のドキュメントは確認済みですがそれっぽい情報は見当たりませんでした。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101767

Comment: すみません。ダメなんですね。どっちか選ばないといけないのは難しいですね

Comment: stackoverflowは特にマルチポストを禁止していません。一方、teratailには規約があります。質問者さんは双方に情報を共有して頂けると、回答する人は助かります。

Comment: マルチポストのご指摘・説明ありがとうございました。実体は定義されておらず自分で疑似的に作るしかないという認識で落ち着きました。

Comment: 利用しているサイトの規約は守る必要があります。@htbさんが仰るように、teratailでは[ヘルプ｜teratail（テラテイル）](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)でマルチポストに触れていますが、@makoto さんはそれを守っていないので、teratailの規約違反という事になります。
また、ルールではありませんが、
[マルチポストがマナー違反の理由](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88#.E3.83.9E.E3.83.8A.E3.83.BC.E9.81.95.E5.8F.8D.E3.81.AE.E7.90.86.E7.94.B1)は知っておいて損はないと思います。

Comment: この質問はteratailで解決済なので、「他のコミュニティーで付けられた回答を知らずに同内容の回答を付けてしまったり、他のコミュニティーですでに解決したことを知らずに検討を続けたり、善意の回答者の労力が無駄になる。」の状況になっています。